# My KNN result not as expected for all numerical data

Tags: r, knn, imputation

I have developed the following KNN code and tested it against several datasets with >90% accuracy (the wdbc dataset from UCI for one, granted it was a categorical result), however when using the same code with the pima Indians diabetes data set I get very poor results. I am trying to impute the BMI from the adjacent columns. I have removed the 0 values of the BMI and separated the data set into 70% train/30% test.  Then set up the BMI for labels etc.  My accuracy is 1% and I cannot understand why.  Somehow I have missed cleaning the data correctly but I cannot find where I am missing this. Any help is appreciated.
Here is the code and a data sample is below that:

```
#new script to predict Pima Indians diabetes 
setwd("C:/Users/jbrow/Desktop/kaggle/pima")

#load tidyverse
library(tidyverse)

#read in the csv file to a data frame
pima.full <- read.csv(file = "diabetes.csv", header = TRUE)

#we will use pima.work as the working data frame
#scale the data - necessary for the Euclidean distance to work 
  properly
#create a function to normalize data from 0 - 1

#remove all the BMI equal to 0 and select the columns with 
correlation to BMI
work.df <- pima.full %>% filter(BMI != 0) %>% select(2,3,4,5,6)

#create normalization functions
data_norm <- function(x){((x - min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))}
data_denorm <- function(x){x*(max(x)-min(x))+min(x)}

pima.norm <- as.data.frame(lapply(work.df[,-5],data_norm))

#split the data set into training and testing
set.seed(123)

#number of training rows of the total data
sizedf <- floor(0.7 * nrow(pima.norm))

#get the row numbers
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(pima.norm)),size = sizedf)

#training data from four relevant normalized columns 
data_train <- pima.norm[train_ind,]
#testing data from same normalized columns
data_test <- pima.norm[-train_ind,]
#training labels - column 6 - BMI
train_labels <- work.df[train_ind,5]
#testing labels
test_labels <- work.df[-train_ind,5]

#model run
#install.packages('class')
library(class)

knn.BMI <- knn(train = data_train, 
              test = data_test, 
              cl=train_labels, 
              k=round(sqrt(nrow(data_train))))

# plotting results
con_mat = as.matrix(table(Actual = test_labels, Predicted = 
         knn.BMI))
knn_acc = sum(diag(con_mat))/length(train_labels)
```

I have tried the same code logic against other datasets with good results so I believe the issue lies with preparing the data. Kind of at a lost now.

Apologies that I cannot get the tables to print legibly but the data sets are from the pima indian set on Kaggle.

columns from work.df:   Glucose BloodPressure SkinThickness Insulin  BMI

columns (normalized) from pima.norm: Glucose BloodPressure SkinThickness   Insulin

Comment: This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you need help improving the fit of a statistical model, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there.